# What is the funniest firewall rule set?

Tags: security, firewall, web-application-firewall

What is the finniest firewall rule set that you know of?  It doesn't necessarily have to stop attacks,  you could just be having fun with the attacker.  Any type of firewall will do,  Packet Filter (like iptables) or even a Web Application Firewall(like mod_security).

Comment: Wow, how is this not a real question?

Comment: Keep in mind that this site was designed to provide answers for specific questions and problems that professional system administrators encounter. Something like 85% for the traffic of stackoverflow comes from google, to give you an idea. This could have been an amusing page, but I guess the people that closed it thought didn't really fit with the general philosophy of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal favorite is the [Upside-Down-Ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html).